# How do you edit or delete text in a tableView?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying have the user to modify/delete default text in a tableview, I have tried the following code witch works but as soon as the user goes to the other view controller and back (or leaves the app and comes back), the text goes back to being the default text.
How could I have it work? 
I have posted the entire code for the tableView so you can have an overview of what I could have done wrong.
thank you !

```
var places = [Dictionary<String,String>()]

var activePlace = -1

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    func companyNameUpdatedAlert(title: String, error: String, indexPath: Int) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in

            textField.placeholder = "Enter new text"

        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            let lat = places[indexPath]["lat"]!

            let lon = places[indexPath]["lon"]!

            places.removeAtIndex(indexPath)

            places.insert(["name" : alert.textFields![0].text!, "lat" : lat, "lon" : lon], atIndex: indexPath)

            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let changeText = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Change text" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in

            self.companyNameUpdatedAlert("Update text", error: "enter text below", indexPath: indexPath.row)

        })

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in

            places.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            tableView.reloadData()

        })

        return [changeText, deleteAction]


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //save start

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") != nil {

            places = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") as! [Dictionary]


            //save stop

        super.viewDidLoad()



        if places.count == 1 {

            places.removeAtIndex(0)

            places.append(["name":"Long press on map to add location","lat":"90","lon":"90"])



        }
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") != nil {

            places = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") as! [Dictionary]


        }

    }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return places.count


    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]

        return cell



    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        activePlace = indexPath.row

        return indexPath

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "newPlace" {

            activePlace = -1


        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        tableView.reloadData()


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit the table you should persist your data in the `NSUserDefaults`. Otherwise you are just changing the class property which is reloaded from the original `NSUserDefaults` each time the class loads.

Try this inside your `UIAlertAction` closure:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "places")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had been stuck on that for a while